# “It never truly sunk in, ...”: Sunk or sank?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

I just began reading *The Only Grammar Book You’ll Ever Need* by Susan Thurman. On the first page of the *Introduction* chapter, the author wrote

> “Maybe all that talk in English class about parts of speech and dangling participles never truly sunk in, ...”

I’ve researched the differences between *sunk* and *sank*: *sunk* is the past participle of *sink*, and *sank* is the past tense. However, I still cannot tell whether the usage of *sunk* in the aforementioned excerpt is correct. This is likely because my understanding of past participles and past tenses is not sophisticated enough.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this and provide an explanation.

Comment: **Sunk** is the "**past and past participle of sink."**

Comment: _Sunk_ and _sank_ vary as the past tense form of _sink_, much like [_shrunk_ and _shrank_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/603171/15299). It's part of English's loss of inflection. Regular verbs have the past and participle forms with identical _-ed_ suffixes, basically wiping out the distinction; and now they're coming for the irregular verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some speakers, the phrasal verb *sunk in* sounds better than *sank in*. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+really+sank+in%2C+never+really+sunk+in&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20really%20sank%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnever%20really%20sunk%20in%3B%2Cc0) shows that *never really sank in* and *never really sunk in* are about the same.

The Oxford Dictionary online has a usage note at *[sink](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sink)*:

> Historically, the past tense of sink has been both *sank* and *sunk* (the boat sank; the boat sunk) and the past participle has been both *sunk* and *sunken* (the boat had already sunk; the boat had already sunken). In modern English the past is generally sank and the past participle is sunk, with the form sunken now surviving only as an adjective, as in a sunken garden or sunken cheeks.

Which coincides with my American English experience of almost always  using or hearing only *sank* as the past simple. To me, *sunk* as the past simple seems marked or off or nonstandard or pirate or drunk pirate or drunken pirate, but your mileage may vary.

So that's probably not the only grammar book you'll ever need.

Comment: The behavior is weird because this is one of those unaccusative verbs. Sunk is still regularly used in the simple past when the subject is agent. It sank on its own. We sunk it with torpedoes. It is also used when something is already under water and sinks deeper. It initially sank onto a ledge, then it sunk another 100 meters. *Sunk in* is a phrasal verb and has its own quirks.

Comment: I agree about *sunk in*. @PhilSweet

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. So *sunk in* seems to be correct in this case?

Comment: I've added an Ngram to my answer. It shows nearly equal usage. But I haven't looked at any of the actual usages yet (you can do this by clicking on the red and blue links at the bottom. I suppose *sunk in* might sound better, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* says the past of *sink* is "*sank* or *sunk*", and the past participle is *sunk*.  So this sentence is still correct, even it is the simple past (I think it is).