# Why do some irregular verbs, such as swing/swung and sting/stung, only have two forms instead of three?

Tags: etymology, history, historical-change, irregular-verbs

Folks, my question has to do with really difficult things to understand, so I've chosen this forum and think only truly wise owls are able to help me.

As you, I hope, know, lots of English irregular verbs were taken from German, but ever since, a very long time has passed, so at least half of those have become too archaic (like *step-stope-stopen*).

So, lots of them are really like German irregular verbs, for example:

1. German: ringen-rang-gerungen.
   English: ring-rang-rung.
2. German: springen-sprang-gesprungen.
   English: spring-sprang-sprung.

My question is why have some of **such** verbs changed a little bit by changing their root *a* to *u* in the English language?

Examples:

1. German: swingen-swang-geswungen.
   English: swing-swung-swung (*swang* is no longer acceptable as the past simple of *swing*)
2. German: stechen-stach-gestochen.
   English: sting-stung-stung (now, *stang* is half-acceptable, yet it's very seldom used in speech).

Comment: I have wondered also about irregular verbs, why sometimes the different tenses do not resemble each other at all. A very good example is "to go." How is "went" the past tense of "go"?? My belief is that while a modern person understands going in the past is just a special case of going, this was not understood when these words were coined. "To be" in both German and English is equally baffling. I believe Chinese deals with tense much more "rationally."

Comment: *How is "went" the past tense of "go"??* It's called *suppletion*; *went* is from a different root than *go*.  As explained at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/are-there-other-verbs-like-be-and-go/28515

Comment: *As you, I hope, know, lots of English irregular verbs were taken from German*, That is a gross and misleading simplification. It also ignores the fact that in Modern German it is, and Old English it was, usual for the past participle to be suffixed by "ge-", thus whether the vowel changed or not, the two could be distinguished. In transitional OE, the "ge-" was lost and some verbs ended up with only two forms - so to speak.

Comment: The majority of the verbs you are referring to are *not* irregular (as are the verbs to be and to go) but **strong**.  In fact they have a regularity in vowel change that is such that children given nonsense words will construct appropriate forms of the preterite and the perfect. Note also that Germanic words in English are not derived from German, but both are derived from the same proto-Germanic sources.

Comment: related: [Irregular verbs: the history of the suffix “-en” in the past participle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429673/irregular-verbs-the-history-of-the-suffix-en-in-the-past-participle)

Comment: @releseabe Chinese doesn't really have tenses in the western sense. The concept we refer to as tense is primarily conveyed by context. What they have is the particle 'le' which means that the action of the verb it follows is complete. This is sometimes presented as a past tense to westerners but it is not. You can have the sentence "Wo kan shu" which means "I read book". But if you say "Zuotian wo kan shu" it means "Yeasterday I read a book" and if you say "Mingtian wo kan shu" it means "Tomorrow I will read a book" if you add 'le' after 'kan' it means that the task is, or will be, complete.

Answer (score 5):

I take this question to be motivated by the phenomenon recently exemplified in the title of the movie *Honey, I Shrunk the Kids*, where the normal past tense form *shrank* of the irregular verb *shrink* has been displaced by *shrunk*, the past participle form. I.e,

- *shrink, shrank, shrunk* is parallel to *sing, sang, sung* and *ring, rang, rung*
  with three different verb forms using three different vowels (just as in German)

but

- *shrink, shrunk, shrunk* is parallel to *wring, wrung, wrung* and *sit, sat, sat*
  with only two verb forms: identical past and past participle forms, using a different vowel from the first.

This, in turn, is part of a very gradual shift from irregular to regular for English verbs. English regular verbs all have the following two characteristics

1. There are only two verb forms - the infinitive/present, and the past/participle (like *sit, sat, sat*)
2. Past and Participle forms identically end in *-ed/t* (unlike *sit*, with a vowel change instead of a suffix)

What's happened to many irregular English verbs is that they've lost the third distinctive form and now have only two, and that's come from merging the past and the participle forms, which are often confused in the grammar anyway. So they're gradually calving off newer, more regular verbs, and eventually all but the most common will default to regularity. About the time English loses **all** its inflections and becomes analytic, like *hit, hit, hit*.

Comment: Good, this answer should be just what the asker is looking for. // As a matter of trivia, Wikipedia mentions [which common strong verbs of class 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Modern_English) have reduced their original threefold *i/a/u* pattern to twofold ones, something which can vary a bit by region and register, writing “one of which may be dialectal or archaic” and listing *begin, drink, ring, shrink, sing, slink, spin, spring, stink, swing, swim*, and *wring* as examples of verbs where using a twofold pattern is—in effect—not considered “highbrow” use today.

Comment: Other examples: "bit" replacing "bitten," "got" replacing "gotten," "spoke" replacing "spoken," and "speaked" gradually becoming accepted as a substitute for both.

Comment: _Got_ and _gotten_ are a split, like _dived, dove_ or _shined, shone_ -- neither replaces the other; they're both used, but in different contexts. It's always been a tendency to change the past tense to the participle form -- if you look at what got written down as "dialect" in the 19th century, you find many examples of this -- _He drunk it all down in one go_.

Comment: Ah, right, "gotten" is a recent Americanism.

Comment: Per Ngram Viewet, [bitten to bit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+bit%2Che+was+bitten&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0) is a better example.

Comment: @alphabet [It is absolutely ɴᴏᴛ ‘a recent Americanism’](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/77994)! Indeed you have it completely reversed: the loss of *gotten* is merely a **recent *Britishism***; North American dialects have never for**gotten** how to use it. *Gotten* has always been perfectly common everywhere, ever since early Middle English onwards, right up until quite recently in those British dialects that have lost it (outside *ill-gotten*). We have [many, many questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20got%20gotten&searchOn=3) and answers about this matter.

Comment: 'Shrank' and 'wrang' are still part of my own vocabulary and I suggest also that of many of my fellow native Brits. Is BrE preserving the three-fold form better than AmE, perhaps ?

Comment: Given that BrE consists of several dozen dialects (far more than in the US), there's no ready answer to that. It's been a **long** time since there was a general sociolinguistic survey of England, let alone the UK.

Comment: Strong, John, strong. They are not irregular.

Comment: @alphabet As the man with the diamond says, gotten is originally a British form (it is found in the [Authorized version of the Bible](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/words/Gotten)) which died out in Britain but not the US. If you want an invented American strong verb form, dove (from dive) is what you are after. See [this Merriam-Webster piece](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/dived-or-dove-which-is-correct).

Comment: Sounds like my comment strack a nerve.

Comment: (And now I worry that my reputation [sunk](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reputation+sank%2Creputation+sunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3).)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in Old English there was a difference for strong verbs between the vowel used in the singular past tense forms and the vowel used in the plural past tense form: you would say *iċ wrang* "I wrung" but *wē wrungon* "we wrung", *iċ swang, wē swungon* and so on.

It is possible that for some verbs the vowel of the plural rather than the singular was generalized when English came to use just one stem to form all simple past tense forms. Why different verbs turned out differently is something that I have no idea how to explain.

It is also of course possible for verbs to have joined this class later on by the process of analogy.

Comment: The most obvious case, at least in the context of your answer, of a verb which later joined this class by analogy is *ring*. Originally a weak class 1 verb, it became more and more of a strong class 3 verb starting in the 1300s, probably by analogy with *wring* or with *sing*, which always were such.